# Send HTML custom header to external link

Tags: c#, iis, header, reverse-proxy

I have the following scenario:

1. IIS with the reverse proxy to an external application.
2. In that reverse proxy, I have set a custom header value (user) and defined a static value `user-a`. that external application uses it for its routine.
3. TO-DO => I must call that reverse proxy URL and dynamically change that custom header value in my c# MVC website so that external app can use it.

Do you think a way to do it? Have tried all sort of things.....
Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried a custom module installed into GAC to manipulate  the requests to ARR?

Comment: no.... have no idea how to do it...